# Regarding upgrade to Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Since we've noticed the update of Magento into the version 2.0, which has been a great update I have a serious query.

Basically the thing is that, I have a theme installed on my magento, and I am worried about its working after the upgrade of Magento. The theme is ULTIMO which is available on themeforest.

Can someone let me know if things are gonna get problematic on update of Magento, i.e. will my settings get any issues, and also will my theme face any issues?

Would be glad if someone can guide me through it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to migrate the Ultimo Theme into Magento2. The Theme Structure of Magento2 has changed completly. You have to use the Luma Theme or wait for the Magento2 Version of Ultimo Theme.

Comment: Okay, that's cool for an answer, I would like to ask, will the settings get upgraded without any fuss?

Comment: Please specify your Question. Do you mean the Settings of the Theme itself?

Comment: I mean the settings that are in general with Magento, like for the simplest example - Website name. Get my point?

Comment: Most of settings should migrated properly. But in any case you need to verify it by self.

Comment: Magento 2 comes with a migration data tool. You can install it via composer. It lets you migrate several data from your magento1 installation like sys-config or products. See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Comment: The core_config_data table hasnt changed, so you should be able to migrate the configuration in your system easyly.